# random distribution vectors on cube edges

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

How can I put randomly eight vectors with length `b` into eight edges of a cube with side of `a` and specify them with their orientation relative to original frame.  Suitable way is showing them by

```
d[1]={bcos[thetax[1]]i+bcos[thetay[1]]j+bcos[thetaz[1]]k}
d[2]={bcos[thetax[2]]i+bcos[thetay[2]]j+bcos[thetaz[2]]k}
.
.
.
```

i,j,k are unit vector in x,y,z directions and thetax,thetay and thetaz are relative angles of vectors to x,y,z axis respectively.

In this naming I am able to apply the main goal containing vector manipulations.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do with those vectors? Further calculations? Display them only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For view I would suggest the following:

```
b = 1;
a = 2;
cor = Tuples[{0, a}, 3];
arrwos = {#1 - #2, #1 + #2} & @@@ 
   Transpose[{cor, b/2 Normalize /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {8, 3}]}];
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0], 
   Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, a, a}]}, {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[cor]}, 
  Arrow /@ arrwos}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful and great.